# cannot use document[0] (type uint8) as type []byte in function argument

Tags: types, go

I'm trying to get a JSON string pulled from a document and into SimpleJson in GOlang, though I've run into a problem with the types (again..)

I get the following error:

> cannot use document[0] (type uint8) as type []byte in function argument

and the line which bugs up is:

```
js, err := simplejson.NewJson(document[0])
```

Could anyone please help me fix this, and also is there a good place I can read up about types and conversions? Having come from php which has no types and python where the conversions are simple, GO is a bit confusing on this front.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `uint8` is simply an alias for `byte`. Therefor `[]uint8` is the same as `[]byte`.

What the error message tells you is that document[0] is of type `uint8` and not `[]byte`

From your comment it is clear that `document` is a `string`. You should just convert it to []byte. If the JSON data in itself contains an array, you must *first* parse the document (pass it to NewJson) before you can retrieve the first value of the JSON array.

So, instead change your code to:

```
js, err := simplejson.NewJson([]byte(document))
// error testing
jsonArray, err := js.Array()
// more error testing
fmt.Println(jsonArray[0])
```

(I assume you have imported the `github.com/xiocode/toolkit/simplejson` package. The only one I could find with simplejson.NewJson)